# LARAVEL + VUEJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js

tengo un problema con laravel y vuejs, el cual es que no me aparece lo que tengo en el ARCHIVO.VUE estoy recién empezando a usar vue lo cual me parece genial, pero tengo dicho problema, nose si uds lo podrán ver, cree todo como se hace normalmente, adjuntare las imágenes y código, desde ya gracias!

[image: ERROR]

index_inventario.blade.php

```html
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
        <inventario-component />
</div>
@endsection
```

inventariotable.vue

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>NUEVA 1</h1>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <h2>NUEVA </h2>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

APP.JS

```js
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('inventario-component', require('./components/inventariotable.vue').default);
Vue.component('notas-component', require('./components/NotasComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

Comment: Creo que está en la forma en la que llamas a tu archivo Vue. Debería ser: `InventarioComponent.vue`. Estoy seguro que si usas notas-component, sí te servirá este. Los componentes de Vue tiene una "regla" para llamarse e invocarse dentro de los archivos. Vue entiende que si usas PascalCase, este se transformará en un componente llamado pascal-case. Puedes ver más [acá](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Name-Casing)

Comment: si lo lei, lo intente de ambas formas pero aun nada, cambie el nombre a InventarioComponent.vue al igualmente la sentencia para llamar, pero aun asi nada...:c

Comment: estaba viendo un tutorial y me menciono colocar esto <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script> y me funciono si me lo podrias explicar seria ideal ya que en el tutorial no decia por que jaja

Comment: Bueno, al final fue algo más sencillo. Claro. Ese script es el que busca y crea el punto de montaje dentro tu archivo blade en laravel, sin eso, Vuejs nunca reconocerá dónde está su punto de montaje y qué componente debes renderizar. Imagina que es como el cdn de jQuery. Si no lo usas correctamente, nunca podrás usar las funcionalidades del mismo. En Vuejs es más o menos lo mismo.

Comment: @MatiasMuñoz por eso siempre es altamente recomendable mirar la [doc. oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend#writing-javascript), checa el párrafo que inicia con: **By default, the Laravel webpack.mix.js file compiles .....................**

Answer (score 0):

la sintaxis de autocerrado de etiquetas es de uso del vue compiler

```
<inventario-component />
```

para que blade interprete el script que genera vue debes tener la correcta apertura del elemento, puedes reemplazar tu componente así

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
   <inventario-component > <inventario-component />
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: si lo había realizado cómo comentaste pero no me sirvió, lo único que realmente me ayudo fue la linea de código que agregue en el .vue, que fue "<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>"